# how to pass jquery value to php module?

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a jquery function:

```
this.getParameters = function(/*sSort*/) 
    { 
        return "&parts="+jQuery("[name='parts']").val() + 
            "&region=" + jQuery("[name='region']:checked").val()/* + 
            (typeof(sSort) != "undefined" ? "&sort="+sSort : "");*/ 
    }
```

here i need to pass **&parts="+jQuery("[name='parts']").val()** to the module i google and tried a lot but i am not able to get this done. 
i have to get this value in my module and i have to insert it into database. I am using a client developed MVC framework/CMS
Thanks in Advance,
Ramsai

Comment: I suggest you read more about basic web programming to understand how web works first :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `$.get`:

```
$.get("yourscript.php", { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" } );
```

This is going to send two parameters (`param1` and `param2` to a php script called `yourscript.php`. You can then use PHP to retrieve the values:

```
$value1 = isset($_GET['param1']) ? $_GET['param1'] : '';
```